# How to store jmeter response to an array in order to make request with the given array?

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to create a Jmeter testplan and I need a object that is create with another object reference. I want to create this object 'owner' 100 times and with the response create 100 'devices' in which one of the fields will be an 'owner_ref'.

I want to create the devices with the corresponding ids like

```
ownerId1-->device1
ownerId2-->device2 and so on.
```

Im using now:

```
testPlan:
    HttpRequest
        Json Path Postprocessor--> extract 'id' to variable 'ownerId'
```

How I can create an array of ownerIds and iterate through this 100 to create new request with these ids?

I am thinking in use beanShell but should be another easier and cleaner method to do. 
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) documentation states, you can use `Match Numbers` parameter:

> **-1** means extract all results, they will be named as variable **name_N** (where N goes from 1 to Number of results)

So you could configure your JSON Path PostProcessor like this:

```
Variable Names: ownerId
...
Match Numbers: -1
```

Which will produce variables: `ownerId1,...,ownerIdN`

And then you have a few options, most obvious of them is to use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) exactly as help describes

```
ForEach Controller
 Input variable prefix: ownerId
 Output variable: currentId
```

So now any sampler under that controller can use `${currentId}`